# VBA TextToColumns behaves differently when done manually and when done by macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have encountered a strange problem that I simply cannot get my head around. I have a .csv file which contains 4 columns of dates. As a daily task I have to work with these dates and convert them to DMY format using the TextToColumn option of Excel. The original format of the dates is MDY - and for reasons I don't understand when done manually with Data>Text to Columns>Fixed Width>Date:MDY these dates are converted to correct DMY format.

Here is a screenshot of the raw data in the .csv file:

#### Raw data

[image: Raw data]

Now I wanted to automate it through a simple macro, and after recording the text to columns operation and doing some tweaking to span all 4 columns I have got the following code:

```
Sub Text_To_Column()
'
' Select_Column_Get_Length Macro
'
Worksheets("Outcome extract").Activate

Dim l As range
Set l = range("A2", range("A2").End(xlDown))
Dim h As Long
h = l.Count

Dim daterange As range
Dim firstcell As range
Set firstcell = range("FG2")
Set daterange = range(firstcell, firstcell.Offset(0, 3))
    
For Each n In daterange

    Dim dates As range
    Set dates = range(n, n.Offset(h, 0))
    dates.Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=n, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3)
Next n
End Sub
```

The code currently counts the number of entries and performs text to column operation on that many dates (as to not operate all the cells which I think would slow it down?). Either way the macro currently gives me different results to the manual operation even though all the parameters of Text to Column were taken from a recording.

For some reason the entries which were originally aligned to the right have their MM and DD swapped when done manually but NOT by the macro.

Any hint on where I am going wrong would be much appreciated!

P.s. I know I should avoid selecting cells and work with ranges I will fix that bit once I know this method works.

Comment: FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3) is 1 based, so you can't have 0 as column indicator. Also you have to set this for every column in your range. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx

Comment: Hi Luuklag - thanks for your comment. I have read the documentation but unfortunately could not fix my problem - also what do you mean it is 1 based? From my understanding the first element specifies the starting character position in the column (0 being the first character). Thanks again!

Comment: Being 1 based, means that the first column is 1, not 0.